# CI Bonfire MX/Loader error after php upgrade

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

I am using XAMPP on Mac OS X v.10.8.5 for my local environment and I just upgraded to version 1.8.2-5 which runs: Apache 2.4.9 PHP 5.4.27 MySQL 5.5.36

In my CI Bonfire 0.7 installation I am now getting an error:

> 'Unable to select the specified database:' Filename: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/Internal/fmengine_v_2/application/third_party/MX/Loader.php Line Number: 102

I've run a test in and I'm able to connect to the database directly but the Loader does not seem to be able to connect to the same database.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you please paste in line 102 of the Loader.php file please?

Comment: Here it is:
line 102 CI::$APP->db = DB($params, $active_record);

Answer (score 0):

Well, after beating my head against the wall, googling, and reviewing log files I was able to fix this problem. Here is my solution in case someone else has the same problem.

First I've discover that the php.ini file has three location for defining socket location: [Pdo_mysql] - pdo_mysql.default_socket [MySQL] - mysql.default_socket [MySQLi] - mysqli.default_socket in my case the socket was located at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock

The second thing I discovered is that in the process of upgrading somehow the database user was not updated. After I updated users privileges to the specific db I had everything working again.